# AZURE: async Run() in workerrole

Tags: c#, azure, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0, azure-worker-roles

I have an async task.

```
async Task UploadFiles()
{
}
```

I would like to call 'await' on UploadFiles() in Run() method in azure workerrole.
but 'await' works only in the methods declared async.
So can I make Run() method async like below:

```
public override void Run()
{
   UploadFiles();
}
```

to

```
public async override void Run()
{
   await UploadFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worker roles only have a synchronous entry point. This means that you will need to keep the thread that the `Run` method runs on active.

You can just call `Wait` on the task that `UploadFiles` gives you. Waiting is normally avoided but you are forced to do it here. The cost is not that high: One thread wasted.

Comment: "You can just call Wait on the task that UploadFiles gives you." how can i do it?

Comment: What about `UploadFiles().Wait();`? In case you don't know: `await` does not operate on method calls. It operates, simply speaking, on tasks. And `UploadFiles` returns a `Task`. You can use it like any other task. For example, you can call `Wait` on it. Makes sense?

Comment: This article explains how to do this. [Building Real-World Cloud Apps with Azure](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/more-patterns-and-guidance) and you can download [the sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Fix-It-app-for-Building-cdd80df4)

Answer (score 3):

As @usr has mentioned, the entry point for a worker role only runs synchronously and so you will need to wait on any task you start. Typically however, I find I usually have more than one task that I want to kick off asynchronously from the worker role. The standard pattern I follow is this

```
public override void Run()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(RunTask1Async());
    tasks.Add(RunTask2Async());
    tasks.Add(RunTask3Async());

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```