# Azure WorkerRole API Calls async/await

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure worker role that reads messages from a service bus queue using the `Client.OnMessage()` message pump directive.

Here is a sample code:

```
public override void Run()
{
     Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>   {

         var APIResponse = Call3rdPartyAPIUsingMessageData(receivedMessage)

     }, options);

}
```

The issue is that the 3rd party API call takes a long time. It seems silly to sit there and wait for the API call to complete synchronously.

What I would like is to take advantage of `async/await` to save the thread. 
**Meaning, I want the worker role to "pause this message" and process the next message in the queue. When the 3rd Party API call completes, then jump back in and complete the operation.**

Looking at other answers on stackoverflow (ex: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194842/azure-async-run-in-workerrole)), it seems that using `async/await` in the worker role is not a good idea.

What are my options?

Comment: Look at TPL DataFlow.

Comment: Interesting. In azure, what kind of application/service/webjob/etc will utilize the TPL DataFlow.

Comment: How many concurrent calls would you like to make to the service bus?

Answer (score 0):

Worker Roles are made to run long time processing tasks. That is one reason that they are made for.

If you want to do a different (and smartest) approuch, try paralls:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx

This way, you may be able to process data simultaneously, and certainly have a faster result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to try parallels. Also, Worker Roles can only have their Entry Point synchronous as already mentioned, so you can't change that.

You're looking at the problem from a wrong angle. The ServiceBus QueueClient you're using has a MaxConcurrentCalls option which sets how many threads are going to be used when connecting to SB. Each time you call OnMessage a new thread is used until your reach the MaxConcurrentCalls threshold. So this already scales up to a point

What you want do is the code that calls the API async (e.g. by wrapping it into a Task), not your OnMessage as there is no point to do that one.

EDIT: What I forgot to mention and it's probably the best way, is to use OnMessageAsync in case you have I/O Bound work, just like calling the API in your case.

Comment: In order to call the API calls async - you would want to use the `await` term. To do that you need to make `Main()` async. You cannot make the `Main()` method `async`. Edit: you could, but then the `Main()` method is turned off and the Worker Role restarts - killing your async request Task.

Comment: Asynchronous doesn't necessarily mean async keyword. Asynchronous means a processing taking place without blocking the thread. That can also be done like Task.FromResult(() => YourAppiCall).ContinueWith(nextmethod()); etc. as long as you don't want to return the result to the main thread, you just fire it off and forget.

Comment: What I also forgot to mention is that you don't have to use OnMessage which is the synchronous one. You can use OnMessageAsync which is the most appropriate way.

Comment: Great! Missed that one! Perfect I will try this.